# o codigo nao fica formatado

Tags: javascript, html

meu codigo nao sai formatado ele nao pula a linha como no codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>String</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  let nome = prompt('Digite seu nome completo:');

    document.body.innerHTML += `Seu nome é: <strong>${nome}</strong><br />`;
    document.body.innerHTML += `Seu nome tem <strong>${nome.length}</strong>letras `;
    document.body.innerHTML += `A segunda letra do seu nome é:${nome[1]}`;
    document.body.innerHTML += `Qual o primeiro índice da letra "A" no seu nome? ${nome.indexOf("a")}`;
    document.body.innerHTML += `Qual o último índice da letra "A" no seu nome?${nome.lastIndexOf("a")}`;
    document.body.innerHTML += `As últimas 3 letras do seu nome são: ${nome.lastIndexOf(nome)}`;
    document.body.innerHTML += `As palavras do seu nome são: ${nome.slice(" ")}<br />`;
    document.body.innerHTML += `Seu nome com letras maiúsculas: ${nome.toUpperCase()}`;
    document.body.innerHTML += `Seu nome com letras minúsculas: ${nome.toLowerCase()}`;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: só tem 2 "br", então só vai pular 2 linhas

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de pular as linhas é utilizando a tag `<br>` ao final das sentenças. Exemplo:

```js
...
document.body.innerHTML += `Seu nome tem <strong>${nome.length}</strong>letras<br>`;
...
```

A tag `<br>` tem como função justamente dar um "break"(um espaço) entre as linhas.

Outra forma de resolver o problema seria colocando a sentença inteira dentro de uma tag de parágrafo `<p>`. Como abaixo:

```js
...
document.body.innerHTML += `<p>Seu nome tem <strong>${nome.length}</strong>letras</p>`;
...
```

Desta forma, cada linha será separada por uma linha em branco.